# Issue calling a subprocess from ArcGIS Pro Toolbox

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro, pandas, subprocess

I am developing a toolbox that - at some point - has to process a large amount of data and apply a function to each row. For efficiency reasons I already use a pandas dataframe.

I am familiar with pandas and big dataframes, so thats why I tried using `pandas.series.apply` to efficiently apply the function to each row.

But processing this big dataframe with 100k rows takes like 100s benchmarking the speed and I don't really want to be stuck with a calculation of 5kk rows taking 50 times longer, when it can be sped up by almost the factor of my cpu cores. I have also experienced the time it takes being even longer when using this from inside ArcGIS Pro, where I had like 25% completion after 1 hour of computing time.

So I looked into the option of using pooling and splitting up my dataframe to utilize my full cpu power, and then apply the function to every chunk in their own pool. I ran into some issues with ArcGIS Pro opening new instances of itself when naively trying to use concurrent.futures, but fixed this by using a subprocess like the [large-network-analysis-tool](https://github.com/Esri/large-network-analysis-tools) does.

But that lead to my current problem:

```
    File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access Denied
```

I have already tried granting myself permissions as described here: [Link](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/arcpy-permission-denied-errors-in-arcgispro-2-3/td-p/332962/page/2)

Running the args I put into the subprocess call from the command line works perfectly fine, but the subprocess call seems to have some permission issues, even when starting ArcGIS Pro as admin.

Any kind of hints to resolve this issue? I am fine with sharing some code snippets and rewriting lots of code if there is a better way of handling this amount of data.

EDIT: Here is a snippet from the subprocess call
(I think those double quotes need to be there, because of "Program Files" in the directory path)

```
create_no_window = 0x08000000
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
python_path = os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, "python.exe")
script_path = os.path.join(cwd, "solveTable.py")
inputs = [
  '"{}"'.format(python_path),
  '"{}"'.format(script_path),
  "--in_df", '"{}"'.format(in_df_csv),
  # some more kwargs
  ]
with subprocess.Popen(
  inputs,
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
  creationflags=create_no_window) as process:
  # some code for logging and error handling
```

The `solveTable.py` is parsing the kwargs from the input, splits up the `in_df` into n chunks, then calculates the values for those chunks, saves each result into a `.csv` file for me to read when everything is done. This - as previously stated - works perfectly when executing from commandline.

EDIT 2: Following the suggestion of @dslamb I tried getting `np.where` to work here to apply a function to the series.

Currently I am using `pd.series.apply` like this:

```
lines_df['A_d_j'] = lines_df.apply(lambda d_j:
                              calculateFactors(d_j,
                                 w_df.loc[w_df['GRID_ID'] == d_j['dest']])
                                 if pd.isna(d_j['A_d_j'])
                                 else d_j['A_d_j'], axis=1)
```

The `calculateFactors` function takes a single row and calculates some values for each entry in `w_df` that has the same `GRID_ID` as `d_j` and returns a `float`.
The problem I am facing right now is: How *exactly* do I access **each row** to be able to map the function on each value like I do in this above `pd.series.apply`? All I can think about is another `pd.series.apply` somewhere.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I edited the question and added the code used for calling the subprocess and a description of what the subprocess is doing

Comment: Can you clarify when you say toolbox do you mean a python toolbox (pyt file) or a standard script tool (py file wired up to an interface)?

Comment: This isn't an answer for your subprocess problem, but did you try some alternatives to apply, such as numpy.vectorize. Here is a discussion comparing some alternative methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c

Comment: @Hornbydd it is indeed a .pyt file, not a standard script tool.

Comment: @dslamb thank you for comment, I will try doing this!

Comment: @dslamb I've tried implementing this, but had some problems applying the function with my specific implementation. I added some more code to show you how my `pd.series.apply` looks like and some explaination of my function.

Comment: One thing that might speed up the process is to filter by null instead of using an if statement. lines_df.loc[pd.isna(lines_df['A_d_j']),'A_d_j'] = lines_df[pd.isna(lines_df['A_d_j'])].apply. It may also make sense to try to preprocess w_df to group by the dest field, if you can. I don't know what calculateFactors does, but if instead you can just multiply the columns or extract them as numpy arrays and do the processing, that tends to be faster than applying.

Comment: @dslamb, thanks for the tip, trying this out right now. Regarding the preprocessing: the w_df has less than 100 entries and might never get above 200 entries in a real world scenario so I don't really see room for improvement here. CalculateFactors is looking up some values in other tables, I think i should really merge this into the w_df beforehand.

Comment: @dslamb performance is a lot better now, especially the the filter instead of using the if statement. I assumed pandas is pretty good at conditionally applying, but I stand corrected. Now I am down to good computing times without the need for pooling and multiprocessing. Thanks a lot!